# Combining Multiple JAXB Element Fragments into one root node?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm figuring out JAXB at the moment and I'm very very close to what I need. Currently my ArrayList is populated from a DB query and then marshalled to a file but the problem is my marshalled objects aren't wrapped in a root node. How would I go about doing this?

```
try  //Java reflection
{
    Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(command); // get the class named after their input
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(myClass);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    ArrayList<JAXBElement> listOfJAXBElements = getJAXBElementList(myClass);
    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(command + ".xml", true);
    for(JAXBElement currentElement: listOfJAXBElements)
    {
        marshaller.marshal(currentElement, fileOutput);
    }
    fileOutput.close();
}
catch (IOException | NullPointerException | ClassNotFoundException| JAXBException| SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException e) { }
```

Here's the account class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="accounts")
@Entity
@Table(name="Account")
public class account implements Serializable
{
      ...
}
```

Here's my output:

```
<class account>
    <accountNumber>A101</accountNumber>
    <balance>500.0</balance>
    <branchName>Downtown</branchName>
</class account>

<class account>
    <accountNumber>A102</accountNumber>
    <balance>400.0</balance>
    <branchName>Perryridge</branchName>
</class account>
```

I'd like to have:

```
<accounts>
    <class account>
        <accountNumber>A101</accountNumber>
        <balance>500.0</balance>
        <branchName>Downtown</branchName>
    </class account>

    <class account>
        <accountNumber>A102</accountNumber>
        <balance>400.0</balance>
        <branchName>Perryridge</branchName>
    </class account>
</accounts>
```

EDIT 1: marshalling objects one at a time produces:

```
<accounts>
    <accountNumber>A101</accountNumber>
    <balance>500.0</balance>
    <branchName>Downtown</branchName>
</accounts>

<accounts>
    <accountNumber>A102</accountNumber>
    <balance>400.0</balance>
    <branchName>Perryridge</branchName>
</accounts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do exactly what you are currently doing and in addition write `<accounts>` to the `FileOutputStream` before you marshal the objects and `</accounts>` after.

You can also introduce a new domain object to hold the list.

```
@XmlRootElememnt
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Accounts {

    @XmlElement(name="account")
    List<Account> accounts;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "accounts")`

[More on XMLElementWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) annotation

How to use it:

```
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "bookList")
  // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
  @XmlElement(name = "book")
  private ArrayList<Book> bookList;
```

Comment: That's giving me: XmlElementWrapper cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Ain't possible. are you sure?

Comment: Imported it manually since Eclipse couldn't find the import. I'm now getting: The annotation @XmlElementWrapper is disallowed for this location

Comment: My ArrayList is defined dynamically from a query it's not an annotated type that's defined in a java class file. Can I just throw that annotation in the middle of a java class file? Do I then have to marshal the arraylist instead of all of its children?

Comment: You can wrap the list of accounts using a JAXBElement at runtime without annotation and provide the name "accounts" there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933475/jaxb-marshalling-generic-list-with-variable-root-element-name

Comment: I'm using Java generics for my list types. I think that's going to complicate things greatly.

Comment: did you try marshalling the instance directly without using the list of jaxb elements? I think directly marshalling without iterating.

Comment: Marshalling the java objects directly or directly marshal the arraylist of plain non jaxb objects?

Comment: directly marhalling the instance of class account. As there is root element given as "accounts" it will work IMO. Try marshalling that instance directly.

Comment: Alright. For now I keep getting: The annotation @XmlElementWrapper is disallowed for this location no matter what I do. Trying to marshal an ArrayList wrapper doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I mean remove the ElementWrapper annotation and directly try marshalling the instance of account class and not iterate and marshall single element.

Comment: See my edit for what happened with marshaling a single instance in a loop.

Comment: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html see this post by blaise for this. Maybe this will help.