# How to marshall generics?

Tags: java, json, generics, jersey, moxy

I have a server application using Java, MOXy and Jersey. Marshalling single objects to JSON works pretty well, when my function returns a list with some objects (`List<Entity>`), marshalling also works well.

But now I have added a class called Response, that holds some additional information concerning the function call, plus a generic list, like shown above. If I create a special Response class for every entity I have, marshalling would work, but it's not really elegant. So I modified my Response class to be generic (`Response<T>` contains a `List<T>`).

But now marshalling stops working. I tried some solutions souggested here on stackoverflow, but none of it worked. So, please help me out! Thanks!

**Update**: Added minimal working sample to point out my problem

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def jerseyVersion = '2.4.1'
    compile     group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers',   name: 'jersey-container-servlet',       version: jerseyVersion
    compile     group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media',        name: 'jersey-media-moxy',              version: jerseyVersion
}
```

Server.java

```
package org.minimal.demo.server;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class Server extends ResourceConfig {
    public Server() {
        packages("org.minimal.demo.server.api");
        register(JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver.class);
    }
}
```

JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver.java

```
package org.minimal.demo.server;

import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Provider
public class JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {
    private final MoxyJsonConfig config;

    public JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver() {
        config = new MoxyJsonConfig()
                .setIncludeRoot(false)
                .setValueWrapper("$")
                .setFormattedOutput(true)
                .setNamespaceSeparator(':');
    }

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return config;
    }
}
```

SomeEntity.java

```
package org.minimal.demo.server.entity;

public class SomeEntity {
    public int value;

    public SomeEntity() {
    }

    public SomeEntity(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

GenericResponse.java

```
package org.minimal.demo.server.response;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericResponse<T> {
    public List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
    public String msg;

    public GenericResponse() {
    }

    public GenericResponse(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public void addItem(T item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

SomeApi.java

```
package org.minimal.demo.server.api;

import org.minimal.demo.server.entity.SomeEntity;
import org.minimal.demo.server.response.GenericResponse;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/something")
public class SomeApi {
    @GET
    @Path("/a")
    public String simpleString() {
        return "SomeApi.simpleString";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/b")
    public SomeEntity getSomeEntity() {
        return new SomeEntity(42);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/c")
    public List<SomeEntity> getSomeEntityList() {
        List<SomeEntity> ret = new ArrayList<SomeEntity>();
        ret.add(new SomeEntity(42));
        ret.add(new SomeEntity(1337));
        return ret;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/d")
    public GenericResponse<SomeEntity> getGenericResponse() {
        GenericResponse<SomeEntity> ret = new GenericResponse<SomeEntity>("SomeApi.getGenericResponse");
        ret.addItem(new SomeEntity(42));
        ret.addItem(new SomeEntity(1337));
        ret.addItem(new SomeEntity(23));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

When I build the war and deploy it in Tomcat, almost everything works as it should. Opening

- `http://localhost:8080/genresp-1.0/api/something/a`
- `http://localhost:8080/genresp-1.0/api/something/b`
- `http://localhost:8080/genresp-1.0/api/something/c`

in a browser, the expected results are displayed. But when I browse to

- `http://localhost:8080/genresp-1.0/api/something/d`

the following exception gets thrown:

```
Dez 12, 2013 9:21:46 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder mapException
        WARNING: WebApplicationException cause:
        javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
        - with linked exception:
        [Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
        Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
        Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
        Exception Description: A descriptor for class org.minimal.demo.server.response.GenericResponse was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:808)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:243)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:230)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:557)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:381)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:371)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:262)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:361)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
        Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
        Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
        Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
        Exception Description: A descriptor for class org.minimal.demo.server.response.GenericResponse was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.marshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:911)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:401)
        ... 41 more
        Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
        Exception Description: A descriptor for class org.minimal.demo.server.response.GenericResponse was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.descriptorNotFoundInProject(XMLMarshalException.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context$ContextState.getSession(Context.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:787)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context.getSession(Context.java:451)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.getSession(XMLContext.java:356)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.getSession(XMLContext.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:1119)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:869)
        ... 43 more
```

Comment: You can marshal a generic object by specifiying the concrete class as the second parameter to the JAXB marshaller. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933475/jaxb-marshalling-generic-list-with-variable-root-element-name

Comment: In my context the marshaller is not implemented by me, so I can't specify any additional classes.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Here is what you want: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, but even when I apply those annotations suggested on that blog, I get the same exception as before.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, did you ever solve it?